# How to get Frame Names in a page using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there any method in Selenium WebDriver by which we can get all the Frames in a page? Just like we have method for getting all the window Handles.

```
driver.getWindowHandles()
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is maybe what you want then:

```java
public void getIframe(final WebDriver driver, final String id) {
    final List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    for (WebElement iframe : iframes) {
        if (iframe.getAttribute("id").equals(id)) {
        // TODO your stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

It is important however to remind that if your page has too many of these objects, the code may become a little slower, but im talking about over 100+ in my tests when using this solution.

Comment: @aumbire final is this for C# final is keyword?

Answer (score 5):

**Try this code:**

```
    //Assume driver is initialized properly. 
    List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.tagName("frame"));
    System.out.println("Number of frames in a page :" + ele.size());
    for(WebElement el : ele){
      //Returns the Id of a frame.
        System.out.println("Frame Id :" + el.getAttribute("id"));
      //Returns the Name of a frame.
        System.out.println("Frame name :" + el.getAttribute("name"));
    }
```

Comment: cannot implictly convert